# What is the Internationalization Views module for?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

In what kind of use cases would one want to use the [Internationalization Views](http://drupal.org/project/i18nviews) module?  I just discovered this module for the first time today, but documentation on it is sparse.

Since it is already possible to translate the fields and rewrites that are used in Views with the standard i18n module, what does this add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the module code it seems to do the following:

- Adds a Translate operation to the ctools export UI (see the `i18nviews_ctools_plugin_post_alter()` function in the module file).
- Supports translation for views strings: title, header, footer (this is in the `i18nviews_help()` function).

The comment at the top of the module file is:

> This module translates some views strings on the fly using i18n string system

So I would guess the module is just providing internationalisation for some elements of the Views module that don't have it built in yet.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  It also adds a translation context to views strings so that they don't appear solely as "built-in interface."  I'd just note that at least the header and footer can be translated without installing the module as well.